# Given object is not an instance of the class this method was declared in error when trying to set member variable inside PHPUnit test

Tags: symfony, reflection, phpunit, php-7, symfony-3.4

I get the following error when trying to set the "logger" attribute on my class.

> ReflectionException: Given object is not an instance of the class this
>   method was declared in

```
public function testCheckForRecentActivity()
{
    self::bootKernel();

    $plan = new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Services\Courses\Revision0');

    $logger = $plan->getMethod('setLogger');
    $logger->setAccessible(true);
    $logger->invoke($plan, static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('logger.golf'));

    // ....
}
```

The class hierarchy looks like this:

`class Revision0 extends Base`

`abstract class Base extends Plans\PlanBase`

`abstract class PlanBase` which uses the `LoggerTrait` (`use LoggerTrait;`)

`LoggerTrait` looks like:

```
/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

/**
 * @required
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Is there something I am missing that is stopping me from setting the logger inside my test?

Comment: The first argument in your `ReflectionMethod->invoke()` call is wrong. It should be in instance of `'AppBundle\Services\Courses\Revision0'`.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks for the comment. Feel free to submit as an answer and I will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in your `ReflectionMethod->invoke()` call is wrong. It should be an instance of `'AppBundle\Services\Courses\Revision0'`. Also see here: https://www.php.net/manual/de/reflectionmethod.invoke.php

Comment: I have same problem. I understand that OP needs an instance of class `Revision0` but how can it be created dynamically, without of having to hardcode `new Revision0()`?

Comment: Never mind. I found answer myself. Use [newInstance()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php)